# Manual upload of a Docker image to Artifactory

Tags: docker, artifactory, docker-image

For some technical and organizational reasons, I cannot use our Artifactory as Registry by using `docker push` or CI/CD pushes.

As it seems, JFrog's Artifactory provides a feature to manually deploy artifacts, by directly uploading files. Now, how do I do that with a Docker image I built locally on a machine? I only found explanations about JAR Files.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure, but you can try to save your image to a file and upload it via UI.

```
docker save imagename > imagename.tar
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the docker image using the following command:

```
docker save <Docker_Image_ID> > <name>.tar.gz
```

Then untar the tar.gz file and deploy the content of the directory via
[JFrog CLI.](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-how-to-upload-a-folder-with-its-content-to-artifactory/)

Comment: I'll try this. But a first look of the contents of the tar offered several directories with 'layer.tar' files in it. But other Docker-Images in the Artifactory only have a 'manifest.json' and several files like 'sha256_A_HASH_VALUE'